# Merge <li> list with an array

Tags: jquery

I created an `<ul>` list and want to merge `<li>` items with an array using jQuery :

```js
const cards = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to assign `A` to first `<li>`, `B` to second `<li>`, and so on...

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "assign A" to the first list item

Comment: I want to append the index number say- cards [0] should append with the <i class = "fa fa-diamond">;    cards[1] should append with the <i class = "fa fa-paper-plane-o"> and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check jquery  [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) reference

```js
const cards = ['A', 'B', 'C','D'];
$('li span').each(function (i) { /*i guess you  want to  fa fa icons also so added span*/
    $(this).text(cards[i]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i><span></span>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i><span></span>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i><span></span>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i><span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```